# Fetching Reviews from Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have a scenario.I want to fetch reviews of a particular place from google map and place them in my android application.Is this possible or I have to make a webservice and parse the reviews in my application?? Can anybody show me the way?I am using google map V2.

Comment: Go to the `Places API` then

Comment: then??what should I do??

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415827/get-reviews-from-google-map-api ?

Comment: And here's a great documentation by Google https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Comment: gr8 to see that someone is posting links for google documentation for me.I have thoroughly gone through it but was unable to parse the result.Thats why i have posted this question.