# Retrieve contact/place detail using google place api with C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-plus, google-places-api

Hello I am using googleapi to retrieve place details.

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details

i.e.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=ZZZZ&key=YYYYY

I get successfully address, place name, reviews... etc

But how would I retrieve contact information detail?/ place detail? Is there a different api i need to call? Thanks for reading. (circled in red is the information i am looking for).. using serverside C# code

[example](https://plus.google.com/118313857109177916299/about?hl=en-US)

[image]

Comment: Watch this Get reviews from google map api
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415827/get-reviews-from-google-map-api

Comment: @Speakard I can get the reviews but how do I get the detail information in the contact information section, circled in red in the attached image in the question.?

Comment: Why was it down-voted? How do I improve the question?

Answer (score 1):

Check the API reference documentation for :
google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

and this function will be your friend!
::getDetails();

Comment: when I use getDetails() using https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details I get result such as address, reviews.. but I do not see information that is in the contact information section (i circled in red in the attached image in the question post) appreciate if you can help me understand how to get that information.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for premium service of google. That's the reason why you can't find your field in return value of google. Check this out: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details#PremiumData

> review_summary includes a rich and concise review curated by Google's
>   editorial staff. This field will be absent unless you pass the
>   extensions=review_summary parameter in your details request. Note that
>   this field may not be available in the requested language.