# Google API: See Ratings of a Person with ID xyz

Tags: python

I want to get the ratings of a google-user (with id=123456). At the moment I am doing this:

curl "www.google/maps/contrib/" + id + "/reviews"

This works fine, but of course, when I do this more often, google will tell me that I am a bot and will block me, if I don`t solve the captcha!

My question: Is there a solution, so I can do more requests without getting "captcha`d" ?
Is there maybe a solution with the google api ?

Kind regards
James

Comment: You have to use API key check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415827/get-reviews-from-google-map-api

Comment: Thanks a lot :) And this works for customer accounts aswell ? Or just business accounts ?

Comment: Okay, I found the api-check for google-places id and their ratings. But I don`t want to see the review for a place, I want to see the reviews given by a google-user. Is there a chance to realize this aswell with the google api ?

Comment: @Jamez did you ever solve this issue?